Why can't I use an object that I created in an if statement?
I create an object in an if statement like I did before. But this time, somehow, the code won't execute and the debugger says that "the name TempObj is not in the current context", roughly translated. Like he thinks it doesn't exist.
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid.Children.Clear();
    Grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

    foreach (Setting value in SettingList.Values)
    {
        if(value.KategorieName == (String)ListBox.SelectedValue) 
        {
            Label TempLabel = new Label();
            TempLabel.Content = value.Name;
            
            if (value is BoolSetting)
            {
                CheckBox TempObj = new CheckBox();
                TempObj.IsChecked = value.ToBoolean();
            }
            else if (!(value is BoolSetting)
            {
                TextBox TempObj = new TextBox();
                TempObj.Text = value.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Label TempObj = new Label();
                TempObj.Content = "Unable to reach";
            }

            AddToGrid(MainWindow_SettingsGrid, TempLabel, TempObj);
        }
    }
}

The rest of the code executes fine. I tested the function AddToGrid and the shown function without TempObj, or replaced TempObj with another TempLabel, it also executes fine.

The scope of variables defined in a block (i.e. inside the { } brackets) is restricted to that block.

TempObj is unknown outside the if statement. Besides that, 3 branches don't make sense. value is either a BoolSetting or not.

You're creating 3 different variables, all called TempObj, which all have different types. The compiler does not magically create another variable with a wider scope which has a type which is some parent of CheckBox, TextBox and Label. You'll need to create it yourself if you want: decide on an appropriate type (probably whatever type AddToGrid accepts), and declare a variable of this type at the same place as TempLabel

Replace the if statement with Control TempObj = value is BoolSetting ? new CheckBox { IsChecked = value.ToBoolean() } : new TextBox { Text = value.Value };

I think you need to paste the declaraton of TempObj outside the three if-branches with a common base-type, e.g: Control tmpObject.

In C#, variables are only "visible" (can be used) within the scope that they were declared in.
In C#, everytime you have { and } it creates scope.
So, your each if statement is separate scope and the TempObj variable is only visible "under the ifs).
And then you are trying to access it from totally different scope.
But, if you declare the variable in the scope, it will be visible in all "descendant" scopes, something like:
if (...)
{
    var tempObj = ...;
    if (...)
    {
        // tempObj can be used here!
    }
}

So the solution would be to move declaration of variable to enclosing parent scope, but then we have a problem with the type of the variable, but the solution is to choose base Control or FrameworkElement or UIElement (base class for controls in WPF, but it also depends what is the type for the respective parameter).
Having all that in mind, your corrected code should look like:
if (value.KategorieName == (String)ListBox.SelectedValue) 
{
    Label TempLabel = new Label();
    TempLabel.Content = value.Name;
    Control TempObj;

    if (value is BoolSetting)
    {
        // Now it won't be able to access TempObj.IsChecked,
        // that's why we need to initialize like that
        TempObj = new CheckBox
        {
            IsChecked = value.ToBoolean()
        };
    }
    else
    {
        TempObj = new TextBox
        {
            Text = value.Value
        };
    }

    AddToGrid(MainWindow_SettingsGrid, TempLabel, TempObj);
}

This could be written even shorter:
if (value.KategorieName == (string)ListBox.SelectedValue) 
{
    AddToGrid(
        MainWindow_SettingsGrid,
        new Label { Content = value.Name },
        value is BoolSetting
            ? new CheckBox { IsChecked = value.ToBoolean() }
            : new TextBox { Text = value.Value });
}

